# All is gray in The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion

Tags: technical-issues, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have a problem with The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion. I think that this screenshot explain it well:

[image: Oblivion bug]

Practically I see only the HUD and all the rest is gray. Both in character creation and when I try to load an old save-game.

I have an ATI 6850 HD video card with the latest AMD drivers and Windows 7 64-bit. I also tried to revalidate the Steam cache for that game but it didn't change the result.

Do you have any idea how can I solve the problem? There are no mods installed except the default DLC things.

Comment: [Haven't you heard?  Realism is grey.](http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=222)

Comment: That't not good. I wanted to buy the 5th anniversary editio and I  have the same graphics-card/OS setup as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mostly caused by some bugs with newer graphic cards and HDR + AA (Anti Aliasing). Either turning HDR or AA off, or setting HDR to Bloom should fix the issue.

I do not know about any patch that fixes this issue. However, there is a few workarounds to get both of them working together:

- Enabling HDR, and disabling AA in the game options, while forcing AA to be enabled via CCC (Catalyst Control Center)
- Editing the "Oblivion.ini" file manually. Find and change the iMultiSample=0 in [Display] to 4 to get 4xAA.

Comment: hasn't that been a bug since it was released?

Comment: Corret! That was my case, switching it off fixed the problem. Do you know if it is possible play with HDR enabled with some unofficial patches?

Comment: @Drake Edited my answer to add some workarounds to the issue, I sadly do not know of any patches that fixes the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately HDR seems to gray out all, whatever are the other settings.

Comment: @Drake That's weird. I'm sorry, but I got no other fixes or solutions for you :(

Comment: @mordi2k No problem, I will try ask another question, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have an ATI/AMD Radeon HD 6750, also on Windows 7 64-bit, using the current latest drivers. I have HDR enabled, the rest of the graphics settings are at max, 4X AA is forced in Oblivion thru ATI Tray Tools, and I don't experience this issue.

I have the [Unofficial Oblivion Patch](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=5296), [Unofficial Shivering Isles Patch](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=10739), [Unofficial Official Mods Patch](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=9969) and  [UOP Supplementals](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=27710) installed, though. These mods fixes a lot of bugs and might also have a fix for the issue you described.

The mod, [Natural Faces](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=1965) replaces the texture files of the faces to higher resolutions, and might also fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will try to apply all mentioned patches and reply back.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Catalyst Control Center seems to fix it. I suspect GPU scaling may cause some problem since I need it on to fix a black border issue on my 27" screen. I'll try the HDR to Bloom fix if it reoccurs.